# What sentences are applicable?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context, adjective-phrases, conversation

Which of the following is ok and sounds kind of natural ??

1- It has a quality higher than usual.

2- It has a higher quality than usual.

3- It has a quality higher than usual.

4- It has a higher than usual quality.

Comment: (2) is best, because _high quality_ is a set phrase, though we would usually say 'It _is of_ a higher quality'.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting  Thanks.But what about the other sentences are they totally wrong or just un commonly used ??                                  For instance , Sentence number 4 ,I saw it in the cambridge online dictionary .

Comment: I said it was the _best_, not the only correct one or the most commonly used! If one had been completely wrong, I would have said so.

Comment: @kate Bunting  Tanks .